# How to show automatically Caret at the end of new added text to the textArea?

Tags: html

I have TextArea component. In different situation i should append text to it.I want Caret to be appears at the end of new appended text and if text is to large, automatically scrolling down.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with java script.

Given you have a form named "f" and a textarea named "q" this puts the caret inside it:

```
function sf(){document.f.q.focus();}
```

Dont forget to call the method somewhere for example:

```
<BODY onLoad=sf()>
```